# Flask sqlite3 INSERT failure, no error message?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlite

Using virtualenv with python3, Flask and sqlite3 to query a DB from a very basic web page. I am unable to INSERT the data entered into the fields on the home page. The `/what_the_f` page keeps displaying "failure". What am I doing wrong? I suspect the `try: cursor.excecute` but I am at a loss as to understand why this is not working and how to fix it so that the text and integer entered in the home.html pages are inserted into the DB.

The database initialization file:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
connection.execute('CREATE TABLE movies (title TEXT, rating INTEGER)')
connection.close()
```

Database created manually:

`(venv) Tue Mar 07 18:42:38$  python initdb.py`

The python script:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/what_the_f', methods = ['POST'])
def movie():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cursor     = connection.cursor   # <-------------- LOOKIE THERE!
    title      = request.form['title']
    rating     = request.form['rating']

    try:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO movies (title,rating) VALUES (?,?)', (title,rating))
        connection.commit()
        message = "success"
    except:
        connection.rollback()
        message = "failure"
    finally:
        connection.close()
        return message
```

The /templates/home.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WTF? TEST</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>WTactualF??</h1>
    <form action="/what_the_f" method="POST">
      <input name="title" />
      <input name="rating" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am just left with this report from the Flask server:

`127.0.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2017 18:53:02] "POST /what_the_f HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Running Flask in debug mode, I get this when I exit from the server:

`OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my... found it. I had
`cursor = connection.cursor` and it should - of course - be
`cursor = connection.cursor()`

...I will go hide in shame now. Please don't look at me.

Comment: just did exactly the same, slaps forehead